# How do i make a button follow the window size when creating an app with kivy in python?

Tags: python, ios, kivy

[image: As the picture shows the two buttons just stays on at the same position.]When i am changing the size on my created window, the buttons that are in the window just stays put. How do I make the buttons go along the window?
I've tried with "pos_hint:" but doesn't really help.
This is my .py file:

```
import kivy
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import ButtonBehavior
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', True)



class HomeScreen(Widget):
    pass



class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return HomeScreen()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

This is my .kv file:

```
#:import utils kivy.utils
#:import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition
<ImageButton@ButtonBehavior+Image>
<HomeScreen>:
    FloatLayout:  

        canvas.before:
            Rectangle:

                size: root.width, root.height   
                source: 'images/Background.png'       
        GridLayout:
            cols:1
            pos_hint: {'x': 3, 'y':4.5}
            size_hint: 2,1      
            ImageButton:   
                source: 'images/ADD_button.png'
                on_press:
                    print('')     
        GridLayout:           
            cols:1
            pos_hint: {'x': 3, 'top':1}
            size_hint: 2,1
            ImageButton:

                source: 'images/Done_button.png'
                on_press:
                    print('')
```

Comment: When running your example, I get an empty screen. Please post a [mcve].. And don't use source images that are not available to anybody..

Comment: I don't really know how to optimize the source images, so instead I posted a picture of the issue. As the picture show the two buttons just stays in the same position when i am changing the window size @noEmbryo

Comment: Did you read the page I linked? You don't need specific images and fancy backgrounds. But the code *must run* and reproduce the problem. When running your code on my system, it produces a blank window. So nothing to fix. Your screenshot is not helpful to me because I can not replicate it.

Comment: Also, have a look at the [Widget Class](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#module-kivy.uix.widget). Specifically the section that points out that  the `Widget` class is not a `Layout`. Meaning you generally do not want to use `Widget` as a container for other `Widgets`, as your are doing with your `HomeScreen` class. And when you use `pos_hint` and `size_hint`, the numbers you provide are fractions of the parent size. So `size_hint: 2,1` means this `Widget` should be twice as wide as its parent, and `pos_hint: {'x': 3, 'y':4.5}` means the x is 3 times the parent width...

Comment: Thank you for the reply, it worked when I changed "HomeScreen(Widget):" to "HomeScreen(FloatLayout):". Really appreciate it :) @JohnAnderson